# Generic java bean validator type mismatch

Tags: java, generics, bean-validation

I've created an own bean validator as following:

```
public class FromToValidator<T extends HasValidFrom & HasValidTo> implements ConstraintValidator<FromTo, T> {

    //...
}
```

The constraint looks like this:

```
@Target({ TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {FromToValidator.class} ) //Type mismatch here
public @interface FromTo {

    //...
}
```

But I got a type mismatch error, the IDE says `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<FromToValidator> to Class<? extends ConstraintValidator<?,?>>`

I can't see what am I missing.